# php (client socket) java (server socket) cant receive second data

Tags: php

This Is my code to connect java socket :-

```
$socket         = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($socket, '127.0.0.1', 12345);

while(true) 
{
    // read a line from the socket
    $line = socket_read($socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

    var_dump($line);

    $someArray  = json_decode($line, true);
    $otp         = $someArray["otp"];

    if($someArray["msg"] == "otp_generation")
    {           
        $myObj      = new \stdClass();          
        $myObj->msg = "OTP RECEIVED NEED TO CONNECT";       
        $send       = json_encode($myObj);

        socket_send($socket, $send, strlen($send), 0);
    }
    exit;       

}
```

My Question is -

When connection is established successfully server send one OTP to client and received successfully in client. Then i send data to server OTP RECEIVED acknowledgement, it also received in server. After OTP RECEIVED acknowledgement server send welcome msg to client. I cant get the welcome message. if i remove the "exit" code browser is still loading, finally crashing. Why i didn't receive the second data. anyone solve my issue. what i need to modify. am beginner for socket.

I need to display Welcome msg. What can i do?

Comment: When you remove `exit` you have an infinite loop since it doesn't check for a condition to break out.

Comment: Does the server close the connection after sending the welcome message? `$line` will be `FALSE` when the server closes the connection, you should check for that.

Comment: @Barmar server didn't close the connection. It will close after 3 minutes.

Comment: @Barmar if i remove the exit, it will infinite but i cant trace any data from server. If i put exist 1st response will show. Could u tell what can i do. Any examples you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without new line cmd data is not send. This is the mistake i done. Finally i got the answer from my friend.

I just add the line below;-

```
socket_send($socket, $send."\r\n", strlen($send."\r\n"), 0);
```

Thanks @hemanth kumar and @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

You need to continue looping and read the next message, then break out of the loop.

```
while(true) 
{
    // read a line from the socket
    $line = socket_read($socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

    var_dump($line);

    $someArray  = json_decode($line, true);

    if($someArray["msg"] == "otp_generation")
    {           
        $otp         = $someArray["otp"];
        $myObj      = new \stdClass();          
        $myObj->msg = "OTP RECEIVED NEED TO CONNECT";       
        $send       = json_encode($myObj);

        socket_send($socket, $send, strlen($send), 0);
    } elseif ($someArray["msg"] == "welcome") {
        // do whatever you need to do with the rest of the message
        break; // then get out of the loop
    } else {
        echo "Unknown message received";
        var_dump($someArray);
        break;
    }
}
```

I had to make a guess about how the welcome message is formatted, but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Browser is still loading, output is not displayed. could u suggest any other option there for tcp simultaneous connection.

Comment: Are you sure the server is sending a second message? It sounds like the second call to `socket_read()` is waiting for the message.

Comment: yes i develop the server also. it send the second message.  Could you find the solution Please.

Comment: If i put exit "OTP RECEIVED NEED TO CONNECT" message is send  to server otherwise is not send.

Comment: I've added an `else` clause to handle an erroneous message

Comment: Still I am struggled. If i put exit then only write send otherwise is not send. could u check. R if u have server and client could u share me.

Comment: Without more information about your actual protocol all I can do is show a general structure. The rest is up to you.

Comment: If u need anyother information i ill share to you. Could u ask what code u need server or client any file u need. I ill freely share to you.

Comment: Server - https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/L30uKQAr
Client - https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/Wfjzcebb

These 2  are latest dev files. i can't share my java socket Becoz its a big file. So create one php socket server and connect them. please refer it and if u find any pblm ping me.

Comment: One problem with your whole design is that you assume that a single call to `socket_read()` will return everything that was written by the other end. There's no guarantee of that, it could be split into multiple reads.

Comment: So if this is intended as a real application rather than just a simple exercise, you need to implement buffering.

Comment: But other than that, I can't see why it's not working. I suggest you use a packet capture program like Wireshark to see what packets are being sent over the network.

Comment: Not really, it's a complex process.

Comment: Made even more complicated because JSON is not self-delimiting. You need to design your protocol so it knows where the message boundaries are.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Finally i fail in php socket programming. If u have any tuts for multi ready share it to me.